# Can I make emacs recognize double-quoted strings in sql-mode?

Tags: sql-mode

I am looking for a way to make `sql-mode` highlight double-quoted strings in the same way as single-quoted strings.  Setting the product to `MySQL` (which is the correct product for me) did not achieve this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```el
(let* ((mysql (alist-get 'mysql sql-product-alist))
       (syntax (plist-get mysql :syntax-alist)))
  (plist-put mysql :syntax-alist (cons '(?\" . "\"") syntax)))
```

Comment: Works great for me!